# Any way to use Zen Coding for Slim in Sublime Text 2?

Tags: sublimetext, zen, slim-lang

I see that there are filters for HAML in Zen Coding, but they do not seem to be implemented in ST2. However, I would like to use Zen Coding to generate Slim in ST2. Is there a way to do this? Is anyone out there working on a filter for Zen Coding in ST2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is already a plugin for zen coding. To avoid repetition, check out the following link to see how to get started http://www.kingluddite.com/tools/zen-coding-for-sublime-text-2-st2

Comment: The link is dead. However, if you are not attached to ZenCoding itself I found Slim support has been added to Emmet 1.1. Emmet achieves similar functionality as Zen Coding.

Comment: NB: I just found out that Emmet is just the new name of ZenCoding.